# What could be the reason for the difference in date format in query results in PDO and SQL?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, datetime, pdo

I try to run a SELECT query using PDO

```
    $dbh = new PDO('connection string', 'user', 'pass'); 
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id, date_begin, date_end FROM v_accounts where id = 248234999'); 
    $stmt->execute();
    var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

The result of this query is:

```
    array(1) {
      [0] =>
      array(3) {
        'id' =>
        string(9) "248234999"
        'date_begin' =>
        string(10) "01.01.2022"
        'date_end' =>
        string(10) "01.07.2022"
      }
    }`
```

If I run this query(`SELECT id, date_begin, date_end FROM v_accounts where id = 248234999`
) in pgsql database console, I have another result:
    `248234999,0006-07-15,0007-01-12`
Id is unique. v_accounts is a view, fields `date_begin`  and `date_end` are created by this code: `

```
   to_date(date_begin::text, 'DD.MM.YYYY'::text) AS date_begin,
   to_date(date_end::text, 'DD.MM.YYYY'::text)   AS date_end
```

It  works in php 5.6 and php8.2, Postgresql 9.6

What is the reason for the difference in query results in these two cases?

Comment: What's the type of `date_begin` and `date_end` fields?

Comment: The type of date_begin and date_end is "datetime"

Comment: Should you be using `to_date` in your view, this might be assuming that your date fields are strings.

Comment: I think, that to_date is misused, but why it is working in php?

Comment: postgres 9.6 is very very old, but you should also povide a complete [mre], so thatwe can reconstruct your problem

Comment: Are you sure that the PHP code is selecting from the same table/view as the psql select?  This can happen if: 1) They are not both connecting to same database 2) They are connecting to same database but the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) is different and they are looking at different views/tables.

Comment: `datetime` is not a Postgres type. What is the actual type shown in the view and underlying table definitions. It should be either `timestamp with time zone` or `timestamp without time zone` or the shortcuts `timestamp/timestamptz`.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Type of "date_begin" and "date_end" fields in the view is "date". Type of "date_begin" and "date_end" fields in the view is "timestamp(0) without time zone".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a column of the [`date`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) data type (there is no such data type as `datetime` in PostgreSQL) you should **never** do a cast to `text`

```
 date_begin::text
```

Why? The result depends on the setting of the parameter [`DATESTYLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/sql-set.html) which can be different in different sessions / clients.

Small illustration in `psql`

```
set datestyle to ISO, DMY;  
postgres=# select date'2022-07-12'::text;
    text
------------
 2022-07-12

set datestyle to SQL, MDY; 
postgres=# select date'2022-07-12'::text;
    text
------------
 07/12/2022
```

So you see that one and the same date literal is casted to completely different text strings.

This does not completely explains your observation, but points to the source of the problem. Simple remove the meaningless transformation of the `date` column  to `text` and back to the `date` (that occurs surprisingly often in a code)

```
 to_date(date_begin::text, 'DD.MM.YYYY'::text) AS date_begin
```

and replace it with a simple usage

```
date_begin
```

If you want to  get rid of the *time component* of a `timestamp` simple cast to `date`

```
postgres=# select now()::date;
    now
------------
 2023-04-15
```

If you really need to transform a date/time column to a string use [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) with an explicit format.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will try to follow your advice!